# Rewrite of Array.join

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6

While rewriting `Array` so I can practice my javascript, I looked at my implementation of [`.join()`](https://vegibit.com/most-useful-javascript-array-functions/#Array.prototype.join). It seems a little clunky to me.

I've tried to cover all the edges, like making sure `separator` isn't null before joining, not adding the separator at the end of the string, and writing some documentation.

What I'm looking for is a smoother way to write this function. Any recommendations about this function are appreciated and considered.

```
/**
 * Converts each element of the array to string then concats them.
 * 
 * @param separator Value to separate the elements by.
 * 
 * @return String of joined elements.
 */
ArrayRewrite.prototype.join = function(separator) {
    separator = separator || "";
    let string = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < this.content.length; i++) {
        string += (i !== this.content.length - 1)
            ? this.content[i] + separator
            : this.content[i]
        ;
    }
    return string;
}
```

A test case is below

```
// This is the main function that other functions are built onto //
function ArrayRewrite(...elements) {
    this.content = elements || [];
}

myArray = new ArrayRewrite("Hello", "Testing", "Testing Again");
console.log(myArray.join(", "))

// Output:
// Hello, Testing, Testing Again
```

Comment: `separator = separator || "";` What's the purpose of this?

(Please forgive me if this is a basic question)

Comment: @Srivaths If separator is not passed into the function, that line sets it to `""`. The line says "separator = (separator if passed) (or if not passed) (set separator to "");

Comment: Ohh, I believe that's only possible in JavaScript! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short review;

- You probably want to cache `this.content.length`
- That check for the end of array is clunky
- separator will change from `0` to `""`, an unlikely edge case, but it could happen
- Why are array elements in `this.content` ? I would have gone for `this[i]` instead
- `string` is not very evocative, I went with `out`

Obligatory rewrite;

```js
Array.prototype.myJoin = function stringMyJoin(separator) {
    separator = separator || "";
    let out = this[0];
    const length = this.length;
    for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        out += separator + this[i];
    }
    return out || "";
}

console.log([].myJoin(","), [].myJoin(",") === "");
console.log(["apple"].myJoin(","));
console.log(["apple","bear","bananers"].myJoin(","));
```

Comment: "_separator will change from `0` to `""`_" - when will this happen? e.g. if the parameter is undefined, per first line of the function?

Comment: `console.log(["a","b"].myJoin(0))` will return `ab`